# Name for indexed set of groups $(G_n)$ with products $G_k \times G_l \to G_{k+l}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, higher-category-theory

In group theory the following structure appears quite often: a sequence of monoids or groups $(G_n)_{n \geq 0}$, s.t. $G_0 = \{e\}$ together with associative and unital products $\otimes: G_k \times G_l \to G_{k+l} $ such that $$(a \otimes b) \circ (c \otimes d)=(a \circ c) \otimes (b \circ d).$$
Examples would be the set of all finite symmetric groups $S_n$ or braid monoids/groups $B_n$.

Is there a name for this kind of structure? The reason I ask is that I'm dealing with exactly this kind of structure one categorical level higher, so I have 2-groups instead of groups, etc and I don't want to invent new names for well-known structures.

Comment: I can see two possible structures but I am not sure whether either of them is what you are looking for. What you describe here looks a bit like a graded algebra, except that for a graded algebra you want the groups $G_n$ to be commutative; you can probably define a graded object which corresponds to your situation. In a more advanced level, especially for symmetric/braid groups, you may want to have a look at FI-modules